# How to swipe a frgaments inside viewpager using robolectric in android

Tags: android, junit4, robolectric

I want to swipe the `fragments` `left` and `right` which is added inside a `viewpager` .But i am not able to get a method in `robolectric` .Is there any way to achieve this in robolectric

Comment: I dont know about 'robolectric'.. try this link
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: I am talking about scrolling viewpager in junit testing using robolectric.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this..

```
// ... initialise your activity using Robolectric.buildActivity().create().start().visible() etc. 
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) myActivity.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.view_pager_tabs);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(idOfFragmentInterestedIn); // or use getCurrentItem()+1 to go right
```

When I tried this, I had some problems with the Fragments not getting loaded in the ViewPager when testing, but while it definitely occurred only with Robolectric, it may have had more to do with our own implementation rather than the framework, so I can't make any good suggestions out of that.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is to find a reference to your viewPager and set the page (Fragment) you want to display (As Alex Florescu said before):

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) activity.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(desired_tab_position);
```

Then you need to make sure the fragment is added to the fragment manager by doing it manually:

```
Fragment desiredFragment =
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById( R.id.fragmentId );
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add( desiredFragment, null ).commit();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

This will ensure that your fragment is actually created and you can access any view that belongs to your fragment.